# Find global and local maxima and minima, given the graph of the function

Tags: calculus, optimization, graphing-functions

[image]

My attempts were local max: 3,8 - local min: 5 - global max= 3, global min= 5
Module is giving me incorrect. No partial credit. So I can't tell where the problem lies.

local max: 6, 4.?? local min: x= 2, 5 global max= none, global min: 2.

Comment: First, you are listing the *points at which the extrema are obtained*, which is not the same as the *extrema of the function*; to find the extrema, find the value of the function where the extrema are obtained. Second, the function cannot obtain a global maximum at $3$, since there are points where the graph rises higher than $f(3)$. (Caution: it is possible for a function to have no global maximum!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First, make sure they are asking for the location ($x$-coordinate) of the extrema and not for the value ($y$-coordinate).
- I think you have missed a local min.
- The peak at $3$ is not a global max because parts of the graph go above that peak!

Comment: alright. tried again. local max: 6, 4.?? local min: x= 2, 5 global max= none, global min: 2. Still wrong. Any ideas?